# Using Content-Security-Policy, but the code parent.document.getelementBuId() is blocked

Tags: content-security-policy

I using Content-Security-Policy, parent page wraps child page. But the code parent.document.getelementBuId() in child page cannot work.

I made a test. Create A.asp in localhost:80 and B.asp in localhost:81.There is an iframe in A.asp, which point to B.aspA.asp has the code Response.AddHeader("Content-Security-Policy", "child-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' http://localhost:81; script-src http://localhost:81 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';");

B.asp has the code
`Response.AddHeader("Content-Security-Policy", "frame-ancestors http://localhost:80 'self'");`
But when I run the code parent.document.getelementBuId() to get one element in A.asp, the console shows error

*Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:81" from accessing a cross-origin frame.*

So, how can I set Content-Security-Policy and the code parent.document.getelementBuId() can work?
And I also go through the official document and did not get the result.
I appreciate with any answer.

thanks,
Joey

Answer (score 0):

The restriction here is due to the same origin policy, not Content Security Policy, and you can't modify the same origin policy by adding a CSP.

You will need to keep the two frames on the same origin, meaning that the scheme, host and port must be the same.